# Ubuntu + nginx , get information about virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, nginx

I'm trying to shed some light on the structure of the server.

I have one server and in this server is two virtual machines (web_a and web_b)
In this server is nginx + Ubuntu.

web_a project I can open with my server IP + 22 port, example: 123.123.123.123:22

Where I can get information about web_b project port?
Is this information in nginx or Apache settings?
My problems is, that now I don't know how to open web_b.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way(if I understand what you ask) is with:

```
ifconfig | grep inet
```

and in the output will you see, you can find your interfaces for server ip, web_a and web_b

Comment: Thanks, but my server doesn't know "ifconfig" command. Maybe is other way?

Comment: Try with root user or with /sbin/ifconfig